# Is Ctrl+F5 still necessary to force the latest JavaScript to load for a website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications

Our lead web developer is saying:

"The JavaScript code is now versioned in our new code and should automatically refresh when a new version is out.  Yet we are still finding that it doesn’t always work.  Feel free to raise this with Google and Microsoft".

So I'm asking. Is this still "a thing" in 2023? What are some options that he might not be aware of?

I am not qualified to answer this, so that is why I am asking smarter minds than my own.

I searched through the answers here on Stackoverflow and sent them to him. His reply is in the quote above.

Comment: it's true, Chrome (and therefore Edge) often *hang on* to older versions of a pages javascript like they are comforting a dying old friend

Comment: Using versioning *correctly* will definitely work. That means that the way your "lead developer" thinks it's working is probably not correct.

Comment: In general, you append something like the current time in ms to the URL to make it unique.  That way the browser doesn't cache it.  If the file name is the same you run the risk of caching when you don't want it.

Comment: Usually, this comes down to developers not understanding the details of how caching works. In place of learning the intricacies of cache control response headers and if-modified-since, if-unmodified-since, and etag request headers, web server settings, etc. we usually just do as suggested above, appending ?ts=[timestamp] to the URL to prevent the browser from caching.

You might also find it is the parent HTML page that is caching, and still containing your old JS. Best to check the headers being returned for the HTML as well.

Comment: @stdunbar Proper use of `Cache-Control` headers would go a long ways.  We don't have to use hacks like that anymore.

Comment: @KerryF Yes this sort of F5 vs. Ctrl+F5 problem is definitely still a thing.  It's worth noting that different ways of refreshing also affect ServiceWorker behavior, because the folks that came up with that standard assumed it was to only be used for caching.  It's possible for your developer to get around this problem, but it is possible to cache something and be stuck with it, short of changing the URL or waiting for a year until it falls out of the cache.

Answer (score 1):

The way URL-based versioning of any sort of extra content for pages, content fetched by simple GET requests issued implicitly by the browser, is something like this:

1. The build system (whatever that may be) uses some technique for associating a particular number with a complete build, and makes that number available for the construction of the main pages. In the past I've used timestamp (handy for development) and source repository head revision number or release id or whatever.
2. The assembly of the main pages (where scripts etc. are imported) are made to use `<script>` tags with URLs requesting that same version id via a dummy parameter in the URL:

```
<script src="/my/app/goodies.js?_=81992"></script>
```

The dummy parameter makes that URL look like a whole new URL to the browser, one that the cache does not recognize. That will mean that the "is this in the cache?" test will fail, and the browser will fetch the latest deployed file.

Note that the special build or timestamp id value does not do anything other than defeat browser caching.

Same goes for CSS, images, etc.

A weaker way of doing this is computing a nonce value on the client. If you can make a fairly large random number and use it as the dummy parameter, that will *usually* work, but personally I don't want those kinds of bugs.

One more thing: if you have a system that does not involve sessions that can time out (like a non-secured content website), that kind of cache avoidance won't work, because the browser will continue assuming the main page is cached, and it won't have updated script URLs. In that case, you can either go with an "Etag" for each resource, or set your "Expires" headers, or use "Last-Modified" and "If-Modified-"Since" to do time-based checks for cache expiration.

Comment: Note also that this "automatic refreshing" will only happen upon page load. If new code is deployed, but somebody has a page already open, it will never fetch new versions of artifacts unless you have your own code (on the client) to do it.

Comment: A similar way t do this is to append the modified date of the file as a query string param: `file.js?m=07022023202724`

Comment: Far better to do the versioning in the resource name before the query string, to enable better behavior with CDNs which often ignore the query string and won't be able to cache correctly.

Comment: @Brad I have not had experience with CDNs, but the point of this is that the query string **only matters to the browser cache**.  However, of course if there are separate versions on a CDN, then clearly a "real" identifier is required. I don't think this question is about large-scale deployments like that.